# Multiple Colorbox instances on the same page. How can I set a callback to affect only a certain one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have a page with multiple instances of jQuery Colorbox on it. The page is a calendar which displays events, and when an event is clicked, a colorbox pops up with event information.

```
eventClick: function(id) { #.colorbox({href:...}); }
```

Also on the page, I have a button which allows users to change some settings relating to the calendar, and that fires a different instance of Colorbox.

```
$('#showFilter').on('click', function() {$.colorbox({inline:true, href:...});
```

Currently, I have the following script on my page:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){ refetchEvents(); });
```

I added this code so that when the user closes the 'showFilter' popup, some page data will  refreshe itself.  Unfortunately, the above callback, being bound to the document, is executed when both colorboxes are closed.

Is there any way to limit the scope of the callback so that it fires when only the second colorbox popup is closed?

Comment: Any reason you chose to go with the event hook (`cbox_closed`) over the callback (`onClosed`). The callback would allow you to determine which instance of colorbox was called...

Comment: Ah yes, that's because I completely misunderstood the line in the documentation that mentions those callbacks. I just re-read it and understand now. If you want to write that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks :)